# React Dropzone post file to Go server

Tags: ajax, reactjs, post, go

I't trying to use React-dropzone to post files to a Go backend but am having issues.

This is my react code:

```
const request = require('superagent');
<Dropzone name="file" onDrop={this.onDrop} multiple={false} /> 

onDrop = (acceptedFiles) => {
   const req = request.post('/uploadTorrent');

    acceptedFiles.forEach(file => {
        req.attach(file.name, file);
    });
    req.end();
}
```

This is the error on the JS side:

```
XHR failed loading: POST "http://192.168.1.141:8000/uploadTorrent"
POST http://192.168.1.141:8000/uploadTorrent net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

If I console.log the file variable on the JS side I get this:

```
File(61718) {preview: "blob:http://192.168.1.141:8000/a3e9ed9f-6f6c-4471-8322-3591e9e138c7", name: "ubuntu-17.04-desktop-amd64.iso (1).torrent", lastModified: 1506018302216, lastModifiedDate: Thu Sep 21 2017 14:25:02 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time), webkitRelativePath: "", …}
```

Not sure if that is how it should look or not.

I can CURL the server and it works exactly as expected:

```
curl http://192.168.1.141:8000/uploadTorrent -F "file=@ubuntu.torrent;filename=ubuntu.torrent"
```

Here is the code for the Go side:

```
http.HandleFunc("/uploadTorrent", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) { //grabbing the uploaded Torrent File and adding it to the client


    file, header, err := r.FormFile("file")
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(file))
    fmt.Println("File: ", file)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error with fetching file or request issue", file)
    }
```

It always pulls in a NIL value for the file variable when I try and upload from JS.

```
<nil>
File:  <nil>
Error with fetching file or request issue <nil>
2017/11/20 23:54:10 http: panic serving 192.168.1.141:64806: runtime error: 
invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
```

Anyone know what could be causing this?

Update:

I started from scratch with this element:

```
<form  encType="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="/uploadTorrent">
   <input  name="fileTest" type="file" /><p />
   <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

(I edited the backend to look for "fileTest").  This works perfectly.  I am forced to do a 301 redirect back to the main page which annoys me since that is not the react way but I am new to this so I will accept this as a workaround I am satisfied with.

Comment: I'd say your frontend code attaches a file under the form key "name" and your backend code tries to find it using the key "file", and fails. I'd try to debug it by looking directly at the wire representation of your POST request.

Comment: Another approach is to "manually" parsing the form by 1) looking at the `Content-Type` header field to get the "boundary" string from it; 2) parsing it using the `multipart` stdlib package. Read up on the `multipart/form-data` body format.

Comment: @kostix that's not what the posted code shows: `name="file"` appears to indicate the form key is `file`, not `name` as you suggested.

Comment: @Adrian, I was referring to the bit starting with `File(61718) {preview:`. The `<Dropzone>` element (whatever it is) indeed has an attribute `name="file"` but thet some JS kicks in, and it prepares an XHR request and posts it. I have no idea about how it does the preparation so I started guessing from a level below ;-)

Comment: @kostix I'm using https://github.com/react-dropzone/react-dropzone and superagent as described in the react-dropzone example. I think I might have to strip all that out and try a pure js implementation to see if that works.